# StarCraft2: Will I be able to switch between campaigns if I start a new one?

Tags: starcraft-2

Will I be able to switch between campaigns if I start a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a save feature in the menu where you can save campaigns. I'm sure you could use that to switch between different campaigns you've started (though I haven't actually used it myself).